# couldnt hide the progressbar after loading image in picasso?

Tags: android, view, callback, progress-bar, picasso

I was trying to integrate progress bar in ma app.but i couldn't track the call back method.the progress bar always showing.how to hide when image is loded?

```
holder.imageView = (ImageView) localView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) localView.findViewWithTag(R.id.progressBar1);

localView.setTag(holder);
url = getItem(paramInt);
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.fit()
.into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i fixed it.there was a bug in a Picasso 2.0.0 beta.used official library

Comment: Note: The Callback param is a strong reference and will prevent your `android.app.Activity` or `android.app.Fragment` from being garbage collected. If you use this method, it is strongly recommended you invoke an adjacent `Picasso.cancelRequest(ImageView)` call to prevent temporary leaking.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo how do you call `Picasso.cancelRequest(ImageView)` in an adapter? isn't this manually recycled by the `getView()` on the `BaseAdapter`?

Comment: Do you have any news about this topic ? did you get any leaking problem...?

Comment: @chip, I think you can call the Picasso.cancelRequest() within the onError(). Not sure about that though but that makes sense to me. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `VIEW.GONE` instead of `VIEW.INVISIBLE`